# Is there a way to extract text from a cell in excel and make it a comment in a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a schedule and would like to plot out when certain material are expected in the notes on a specific cell within a gantt chart on excel. I am not very familiar with writing VBA so would appreciate any help.

I attached a list of the material and a picture of how I want it to look [Parts List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBOnH.png)[Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxyuR.png)

I tried using something like this

```vb
Sub Comments()

    Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    Set Source = Range("c3:c10")
    Set Target = Range("a3:a10")

    Tmp = Target.Value
    Source.Copy
    Target.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments, _
                                 Operation:=xlNone, _
                                 SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                 Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Source.ClearComments
    Source.Select
End Sub
```

but it could not figure out how to get it to point to the correct date and pos in the Gantt

Comment: to find text then find() or search() along with left() mid() or right()